# How to put /boot on a flash drive?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I have a flash drive with two partitions, the boot loader and one for `/boot`. During the install, on the bottom it asks where to put the boot loader, I chose a partition on the the flash drive, `/dev/sdb2`.

I can make a partition: `/boot` on the hard drive but how can I put it on `/dev/sdb1` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try [GParted](http://gparted.org/download.php).  It will allow you to make changes to anything you want.  Be very careful!

You need to prepare all of the partitions before you install your OSs.  Write down what your partition's names are and where they are (including the ones on your hard drive) so you don't destroy anything you don't intend to.

Or you can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) if you are looking for an easy way to get installation media on the flash drive.

Make sure you back up anything important before you do any of this of course.

If you want to have Windows on the system too, make sure that you install Windows first as it will usually delete anything else it finds otherwise.

If you Have Windows installed already and have Ubuntu on a disk, when you go to install Ubuntu with your disk you should be given the option of doing a dual boot.  [Ubuntu Windows Dual Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Hope that Helps.